# Tag badges awarded in bulk

Tags: support, badges

Tag badges were recently awarded. Pardon my ignorance, was there a recent change/announcement that I may have missed? Did a script fail earlier? It appears to have been awarded in bulk:

**[image: strong text]**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the result of a [network wide bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/295232) with tag scores and associated badges. It was fixed yesterday, Stack Exchange developer @Taryn wrote [quite a lengthy explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/295232) about it. At the moment, it's unclear whether the badges will be redated to their original date or not.